# Timestamp decrease the hour in insert overwrite

Tags: sql, hive, cloudera, impala

I have been work with Sqoop, hive and Impala.

My Sqoop Job get a field from SQL Server with the format **datetime** to write in a TABLE1 stored as textfile. The field in TABLE1 have the **timestamp** format.

After this, I created a HQL script using  `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE2 ... SELECT TABLE1`.

The field in TABLE2 have the **Timestamp** format too, but the time increased in 1 hour, I don't know why.

All the tables was created previously. How can I fix this?

Comment: Utc vs. local time maybe?

Comment: Please provide two timestamps: original and after INSERT..SELECT

Comment: Value field on Table1 =>   2018-10-21 01:00:08  value field on Table2 => 2018-10-21 00:00:08

Answer (score 0):

The difference might come from different time zones (local time, server time, utc, ...)

However, you can fix the wrong values in the database with

```
DATEADD(interval, number, date);
```

Also see: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp for more